# A Dynamic Programming or Graph Algorithm, a Nice Questions

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm

An agent is works between `n` producer and `m` consumers. `i`th producer, generates `s_i` candy and `j`th consumer consumes `b_j` candy in this year. For each candy that sales, agent get `1` dollar payoff. For some problems, one strict rule was defined that a producer should be sales candy to any producer that the distance between them is not greater than `100` KM (kilometers). if we have list of all pairs of producer-consumer that the distance  between them is lower than `100` KM, which of the following algorithm is goof for finding maximum payoffs? (suppose `s_i` and `b_j` may be becomes very large).

```
1) Maximal Matching

2) Dynamic Programming

3) Maximum Flow 

4) 1 , 3
```

this is a last question on 2013-Final Exam on DS course. Any hint or idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, the problem can be solved as a [Maximum Bipartite Matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29), however the modelling requires the graph to be relatively large compared to the original input; for every feasible edge `(s_i,b_j)` introduce `s_i` nodes for the producer partition and `b_j` for the consumer partition and connect each producer node of the to each consumer node of them.

The problem can be modelled as [Maximum Flow Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) on a bipartite graph, however; the flow on each feasible edge `(s_i,b_j)` is constrained by `0` from below and `min{s_i,b_j}` from above, as the flow must be nonnegative, but may exceed neither the producer's nor the consumer's capacity.

Concerning a solution via [Dynamic Prgramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), consider the following sketch of a recurrence relation for Maximum Bipartite Matching. Let `n` and `m` denote the number of nodes in the first and second partition, respectively. Fix a node `a` in the first partition; either `a` is not matched or matched to one of its neighbors; in either case, each possibility is evaluated, recursively evaluating an instance where the partitions have `n-1` and `m` or `n-1` and `m-1` nodes, respectively; the best of these choices is taken.

To put it all in a nutshell, apparently all of the proposed approaches yield valid solutions; however, the modelling as network flow seems to be most natural.

Comment: what do you mean by sd the flow must be nonnegative?

Comment: In fact, you can use maximum bipartite matching by using more nodes. For a producer with s_i candy, create s_i nodes, and do the same thing for the consumers.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will clarify my answer.

Comment: It was a typo; I meant that the flow assigned to each edge must be nonnegative.

Comment: Dear @Codor, which of them is more efficient?

Comment: I would guess that the solution via Maximum Flow is most efficient.

Comment: how i can prove that this is efficient ?

Comment: The Wikipedia link in the answer mentions various algorithms and their respective runtime complexities, which almost all yield polynomial runtime bounds. The bipartite matching algorithm however builds a graph where the number of edges depends on the numbers in the input and will yield a pseudo-polynomial runtime bound.

Comment: i think the (2) is incorrect because there is no order between producer and consumer, and maximum matching is not valid because a producer maybe sale to more than one consumer, and a_i, b_j is large and not fixed so (1) is invalid. am i right?

Comment: Okay, but the modelling as a flow problem is definitely valid; a modelling as bipartite matching might also be valid as nodes can be repeated.

Comment: if the a_i, b_j is fixed, we can repeated node, but now we couldn't repeat it? finally you select which ones?

Comment: Dear @Codor, please see this post, that submit by another user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609624/one-local-olampyad-questions-on-informatic-in-2011

Comment: So is a consumer permitted to consume from more than one producer and a producer to deliver to more than one customer? If so, maximum flow seems most suitable.

Comment: @Codor, producer can sale to anyone that distance is < 100 KM. please update your answer to accept it.